# Regular expression for filtering domains

Tags: regex

Sorry I am new to regex and need help in building regex for some requirement.
I want to know if given domain ends with `.mil,.us,.gov,.state,.jp,.kr,.cn` Exception to this is I don't want to select k12 domains in format (hostname.schoolname.charter.k12.mn.us) EX: (stafford.k12.va.us), (columbus.k12.oh.us), etc.

I am having hard time filtering the k12 domains from the .us domains.
This expression is selecting only k12 US domains, we want to filter only k12 and get all other .us 
`((k12.*.).us|.mil|.gov|.state|.jp|.kr|.cn)$`

Comment: The key words you need to search for to pull this off are alternation (for the optional domain matching of `.mil`, `.us`, etc) and negative lookbehind (to prevent the presence of `.k12`).

Comment: Regex dialects are different - perhaps if you told us the programming language/regex library/environment?

Comment: Excellent S.Jovan your regular expression worked for me exactly like I want. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry, what worked for you?